# Migration guide flask-oauthlib to authlib

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, authlib

I'm trying to migrate a legacy app that uses Flask-OAuth to authlib. The documentation of authlib is fairly decent, but what would be helpful is a migration guide, because I don't really know what parts of flask-oauthlib are similar to parts of authlib.

For example (and this is just one example): `flask-oauthlib` has a class called `OAuth2RequestValidator` under the `providers` package. I don't know if I can safely rip this or what part of authlib replaces this. Also the old code uses `verify_request`. What is the equivalent in authlib?Just a quick guide - `old`: used `this`. `new`: replace with (link to) `this`.

I have looked at the issue [Flask-oauthlib or authlib in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964744/flask-oauthlib-or-authlib-in-production) and the migrations in the `udata` project, but that project is very large and not that easy to follow. A basic `flask-oauthlib` example and just some comments about what classes replace, and where in the documentation would be very helpful to get people to adopt the new libraries.

Comment: It seems a good idea. I will write a post of it.

Comment: Here is a migration guide on client part: https://blog.authlib.org/2018/migrate-flask-oauthlib-client-to-authlib

Comment: I appreciate it and I'm sure others will too. Not being an expert on Flask-Oauthlib, but in the migration I was doing I have noticed things that were done in Flask-OAuthlib that may or may not have a similar thing in authlib. Not sure where to post those questions. For example: token_handler. But there are many more. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've added more information in the blog post.